# Cleanup All populated elements in ng-repeat (Angularjs)

Tags: angularjs

Using Angularjs, Created a search with ng-repeat (2 levels) and populate divs with results, How do  remove the search result when a new search is requested

```
<table>
 <div ng-repeat="one in all" >
  <div id="resultTableParent"  ng-repeat="two in one">
    <div id="results">{{two.details}}</div>
  </div>
 </div>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is a two level ng-repeat, I added:

```
$scope.all.items = []
```

The 'items' were what was holding the result in to "one" (in first ng-repeat)

Thank you all for responding and opening the doors.

Answer (score 1):

you can pass an empty array to all: `$scope.all= []` or put the new results instead: `$scope.all = newResult`

Answer (score 0):

You just must put the new results on the variable of your controller("all" in your case), using the two way databinding angular feature. If you want only clear the results, so clean the "all" variable.

Answer (score 0):

Your ng-repeat uses the array $scope.one, so any modifications to it will be updated in the ng-repeat. If what you're trying to achieve is replacing it just populate it again with the new results. If you want it to appear empty you can empty the array using

```
 $scope.one = [];
```

Comment: I tried to add '$scope.one = [];' and '$scope.two = [];' when search button is clicked. But did not work and using console.log, I see that   $scope.one is undefined, same as  $scope.two, maybe I don't how to make the js file know about my ng-repeat variable (one and two) in the html file!!!